# Execute multiple statements seperated by semicolon in single query in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdo

I found code like this in MySQL for update query:

```
set @c:=0;
update tablename set fieldname=@c:=@c+1 ;
```

It works fine, now I am trying to implement this in JDO. So I wrote the code like this:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL","set @c:=0;  update  tablename set fieldname=@c:=@c+1");
```

But I am getting an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE   tablename set fieldname=@c:= @c+1 ' at line 1

So what is the correct syntax to declare variables in a MYSQL update query?

I removed the set part in the code and edited it like this:

```
 Query query = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL","update  tablename set fieldname=@c:=@c+1");
```

But then I get this error:

> Data truncated for column 'fieldname' at row 254

I included `datanucleus.allowMultiQueries=true;` in my code then also it is not working

Comment: those messages are from MySQL, not "JDO". Consult your MySQL manual

Comment: And what is "datanucleus.allowMultiQueries" ? It doesn't exist. Making up parameter names won't achieve anything

Comment: what should `@c:=@c+1` means? may be you have to wrap it in ' single quotes `'@c:=@c+1'`?

Comment: i have tried it that way also,but not works

Comment: I used stored Procedure to implement this query and it worked.